# Qt QMediaPlayer stateChanged() signal emits infinitely with long music files

Tags: c++, qt, audio, mp3, qmediaplayer

I have connected a slot to a QMediaPlayer's stateChanged() signal. Here is what the slot looks like:

```
void MyClass::mySlot(){
if (mediaPlayer->state() == QMediaPlayer::StoppedState) {
mediaPlayer->play();
}
```

So basically, when the QMediaPlayer object ("mediaPlayer"), finishes playing, I want to restart the song.

The weird thing is, this works flawlessly for short mp3s (around 10 seconds), however for longer mp3s (in the minutes), after the song initially finishes, the signal emits infinitely without the song replaying. Why is this? How could a longer media cause this? I can't understand why.

Thank you very much in advance for any guidance or explanation.